# Do not want to update status

Tags: php, mysql

Good day.
I have a problem with this section of code, the problem is that when making a change, the database is not updated and leaves me in the exception message, this code, I have the original version and the copy, it turns out that probe the copy and I throw that result that I comment before, and I decided to look for the original version, and also I throw the same result, help me to understand why and if there is a solution please silver me.

The connection code is as follows:

```
<?php  
function conectar(){
    $user="root";//usuario de base de datos
    $pass="conto$o";//contraseña de acceso a base de datos
    $server="localhost"; // Nombre del servidor
    $db="hdesk"; // Nombre de la Base de datos
    $con=mysql_connect($server,$user,$pass) or die ('Ha fallado la conexión: '.mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die ('No se pudo conectar a la base de datos: '.mysql_error());
    return $con;
}
```

?>

The form code is as follows:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>addseguimiento</title>
        <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function BuscaDatDep(Ext,Bus,Div,Acc){
                resul = document.getElementById(Div);
                data="Acc=" + Acc + "&Bus=" + Bus + "&Ext=" + Ext;
                document.getElementById('Res01').style.display = "block";
                ajax=NuevoAjax();
                ajax.open("POST", "_php/NewBusca.php",true);
                ajax.onreadystatechange=function() {
                    if (ajax.readyState==4) {
                        resul.innerHTML = ajax.responseText
                    }
                }
                ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                ajax.send(data)
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Seguimiento</h4>
        </div>
        
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form role="form" method="post" action="system/registroseguimiento.php">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
                            <input type="text" name="fechahora" class="form-control" value="<?php echo date("m/d/Y"); ?>" id="datetime" required="" placeholder="Fecha de seguimiento">
                        </div>
                        &nbsp;
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                    </div>
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></i></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="seguiticket" name="codigo" action="addseguimiento.php"  placeholder="Ticket" required="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i></span>
                            <?php
                                $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","conto$o","hdesk");
                                if ($conn)echo "" ;
                                else echo "";
                                $consulta="select * from tienda ORDER BY NombreTienda";
                                $resultado=mysqli_query($conn,$consulta);
                                echo "<select class='form-control' name='select3' id='storelist'>";
                                while($lista=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
                                {
                                echo "<option value='".$lista['NombreTienda']."'>".$lista['NombreTienda']."</option>";
                                }
                                echo "</select>";
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
                <textarea class="textarea" name="viejo" required="" placeholder="Descripci&oacute;n" style="width: 100%; height: 125px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; border: 1px solid #dddddd; padding: 10px;"></textarea>
                &nbsp;
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-headphones"></i></span>
                            <?php
                                $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","conto$o","hdesk");
                                if ($conn)echo "" ;
                                else echo "";
                                $consulta="select * from operador ORDER BY Nombres";
                                $resultado=mysqli_query($conn,$consulta);
                                echo "<select class='form-control' name='select1'>";
                                while($lista=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
                                {
                                  echo "<option value='".$lista['Nombres']."'>".$lista['Nombres']."</option>";
                                }
                                  echo "</select>";
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></i></span>
                            <select name="esta" class="form-control">
                                <option>--- Estado ---</option>
                                <option>Abierto</option>
                                <option>En proceso</option>
                                <option>Solucionado</option>
                                <option>No solucionado</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                &nbsp;
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
                    &nbsp;
                    <button type="submit" name="buscador" class="btn btn-success">Guardar  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span></button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The registration code is as follows:

```html
<?php
    include('conexionbd.php');//incluye el archivo php que contiene la conexion
    $con=Conectar();//variable que almacena la conexión a la base de datos
    $ticket =$_REQUEST['codigo'];
    $FechaHora=$_REQUEST['fechahora'];//capturar datos del formulario
    $descrip=$_REQUEST['viejo'];
    $nombreOp=$_REQUEST['select1'];
    $estado=$_REQUEST['esta'];
    $tienda=$_REQUEST['select3'];

    $query="insert into seguimiento VALUES ('$ticket','$FechaHora','$tienda','$descrip','$nombreOp','$estado')";
    $cierto=mysql_query($query, $con);//insertar

    //preguntar si se insertó el dato
    if(!$cierto){
        echo "No se ha podido guardar";
    }elseif ($estado == "Solucionado"){
        $editar="UPDATE caso SET EstadoCaso = 'Solucionado', Solucion = '$descrip' WHERE codigoticke = '$ticket'";
        $ciert=mysql_query($editar,$con);//insertar
        header('Location: ../index.php');
    }elseif ($estado == "Abierto"){
        $editar="UPDATE caso SET EstadoCaso = 'Abierto', Solucion = '$descrip' WHERE codigoticke = '$ticket'";
        $ciert=mysql_query($editar,$con);//insertar
        header('Location: ../index.php');
    }elseif ($estado == "En proceso"){
        $editar="UPDATE caso SET EstadoCaso = 'En proceso', Solucion = '$descrip' WHERE codigoticke = '$ticket'";
        $ciert=mysql_query($editar,$con);//insertar
        header('Location: ../index.php');
    }elseif ($estado == "No solucionado"){
        $editar="UPDATE caso SET EstadoCaso = 'No solucionado', Solucion = '$descrip' WHERE codigoticke = '$ticket'";
        $ciert=mysql_query($editar,$con);//insertar
        header('Location: ../index.php');
    }else{
        header('Location: ../index.php');
    }
?>
```

It should be noted that the copy in January 2017 the code worked flawlessly.

Thanks

Comment: _"and leaves me in the exception message"_ - And what is that message?

Comment: 1. **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. **You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)** and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: Magnus, the message is one that I have personalized, it is the following: echo "No se ha podido guardar";

Answer (score -2):

as i understood you have problem when only when you gonna run query 
please remove $con variable becuase its not needed when you used mysql.

and please be noted that if you are using php(xampp) version above 5.5 or latest then it will not run becuase php has removed mysql functions. so change you accordingly.

if i suggest then you need to used mysqli so there only minor changes in your code.

i am gonna tell you both way.
for mysql (for php earlier version then 5.5)

```
  $cierto=mysql_query($query, $con);
  $ciert=mysql_query($editar,$con);
```

change to

```
  $cierto=mysql_query($query);
  $ciert=mysql_query($editar);
```

for mysql (for php after 5.5 version or latest version )

```
  $cierto=mysql_query($query,$con);
  $ciert=mysql_query($editar,$con);
```

change to

```
  $cierto=mysqli_query($con,$query);
  $ciert=mysqli_query($con,$editar);
```

please let me know if any concern.

Comment: See about parametrised queries

Comment: 1. Passing the connection as a second param to `mysql_query()` is perfectly valid. 2. You can't just change `mysql_query()` to `mysqli_query()`, you must change _all_ `mysql_*`-calls to `mysqli_*`. 3. Those two API's aren't identical so you need to change more things. 4. For `mysqli_query()`, the link (connection) needs to go _first_, not second as in your example. 5. `mysql_*` wasn't removed in PHP 5.5. It was deprecated in PHP 5.5 and removed in PHP 7. 6. As @Strawberry pointed out, you should use parameterized queries (a.k.a. Prepared Statements).